# The .htaccess redirect unwantedly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want that when `domain.ext/sitemap.xml` is called, `domain.ext/sitemap.xml.php` is opened. *This I got working.*

My problem is that the browser redirects to the php file, I dont want that, it should keep saying `sitemap.xml`

```
# Catch sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap.xml$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/sitemap.xml.php [L]


## Internally rewrite extensionless file requests to .php files ## 
# If the requested URI does not contain a period in the final path-part 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$ 
# test if sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap 
# and if it does not exist as a directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# and if it does not exist as a file 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
# then add .php to get the actual filename 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/? index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Anyone who can tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `http://` from target URI to enable internal rewriting:

```
# Catch sitemap
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap.xml.php [L]

## Internally rewrite extensionless file requests to .php files ## 
# If the requested URI does not contain a period in the final path-part 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$ 
# test if sitemap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap 
# and if it does not exist as a directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# and if it does not exist as a file 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
# then add .php to get the actual filename 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

**PS:** If target URI starts with `http://` then `mod_rewrite` redirects with `R=302` status.